# Don't pick up Django form value to javascript function

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to pick up RadioSelectBox value from my Django form to my template with a javascript part. But I don't overcome to get this variable and put it in my template.

I've a very simple form :

```
def ChoiceTheme(request) :

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = ThemeForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            theme = form.instance.favorite_theme
            print theme
            post = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accueil'), {"theme":theme})

    else:
        form = ThemeForm()

    context = {
        "form":form,
    }

    return render(request, 'Theme.html', context)
```

I get exactly the good field value with `print theme`.

But I want to place this variable in my html template :

```
{% block content %}

<style>
    ul li {
        list-style: none;
    }
</style>

<div class = "col-sm-8">
        <form class = "form" method='POST' action=''> {% csrf_token %}
                <h3> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> Choix du thème DatasystemsEC </h3>
                <br></br>
                {{ form }} 
                <br></br>
                <button> Valider le thème </button>

            <script>
            theme = "{{  }}"
            $(function() {
            $('button').click(function() {
                alert("Vous avez choisi le thème : " + theme);
            });
            })(jQuery);
            </script>
        </form>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

I have `theme = {{ theme }}` but my alert window just display :

> Vous avez choisi le thème :

Do you have any idea ? I'm very sily on this point, because I don't see the way ..

Comment: In your javascript, I read `theme = "{{  }}"`. Is it just a typo ?

Comment: Yes, I don't find How I can write my Django variable inside :/ I tried lots of things but I get `none` or nothing

Comment: Why not just write `theme = "{{ theme }}"`.

Comment: I already tried this possibility and I get an empty window alert.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understood the problem. I think you could pick up the selected theme with jquery, something like `$("theme_id").val()`.

Comment: I have to search in this way, but I don't find a good syntax to do that.

Comment: Fist it should be var theme = "{{ theme }}"; and second theme won't be directly available before processing the form, you should be able to see the value if you click twice

Comment: @AdrianForsius OK so it's what I've done in first time. But If I want to display the selected variable in my form, How I can put it in the window alert ? I have to write one more line ?

Answer (score 0):

To extract the theme choice in django you would have to do an ajax request similar to this:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/choicetheme",
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'post',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.theme);
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery)
```

However you can also extract the choice before sending it to django in javascript but then you need to know what element are in the form IE the option element where you selected your theme.